# Primary Key on Materialized Views with Oracle SQL Data Modeler

Tags: oracle, constraints, materialized-views, oracle-sql-data-modeler

We are using the Oracle SQL Data Modeler to create our new Databases. Actually we need to create a materialized view in a new db schema to provide some master data from another schema. The creation of a MV with the Data Modeler is no problem but we want to create a primary key on the mv to use foreign key. With this constraint we want to secure the integrity of data.

If we create the whole structure manually everything is fine, if we merge this into the design of the modeler we also see the primary key. But if we compare the model with another schema (Testenviroment) then only a unique index will be created and the primary key is missing.

We tried to create the primary key with the script properties but the statement doesn't appear in the script.

Any ideas to handle these problems?

My steps:

1. I created the MV and a Primary Key

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_TEST ( TEST_ID , NAME , DESCRIPTION , COUNTRY_ID , COUNTRY_NAME  ) 
NEVER REFRESH 
AS SELECT
    B.TEST_ID,
    B.NAME,
    B.DESCRIPTION,
    C.COUNTRY_ID,
    C.COUNTRY_NAME
FROM
    TEST@TESTDB B,
    COUNTRY@TESTDB C
WHERE B.COUNTRY_ID = C.COUNTRY_ID;


ALTER TABLE MV_TEST
ADD CONSTRAINT MV_TEST_PK PRIMARY KEY ( TEST_ID );
```

2. I merged the db structure into my data model (Oracle SQL Data Modeler)
   and see the MV, the primary key and the unique index which was created with the primary key.
3. I drop the MV or connect to a schema without these mv and compare my complete model with the db schema und only get a script with the MV and the unique index
4. tried to put the sql for the primary key into the "script end" or "after create" script property but it doesn't appear in my merge script.

Comment: can you post what you had tried so far and what is not working

Comment: i added my steps and an example. i hope this will help you.